# Reports in DHIS2 don't show data after entering the event capture

Tags: dhis2

I am using DHIS2 live package. I defined a simple program without registration so it has only one stage. The program is assigned to an orgUnit in level 2 similar to data elements

Data Elements are

```
Age   -> number type -> Tracker -> orgUnit in Level 2
Gender  -> Two Options -> Tracker ->  orgUnit in Level 2
```

I could enter data in event capture part successfully but I can not see the data in event report page.

What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here,

https://docs.dhis2.org/2.22/en/user/html/ch33.html

I should trigger analytics in Reports->Analytics page.